# I want to curve fit with two independent variables: Tag and Tau . I tried inputting variables with tuple but it did not work

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, exponential

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
```

This is my model :

```
def concentration(T,a,b,c,d):
    (Tag,Tau)=T   
    return np.exp(a-d/Tag)/(np.exp(a-d/Tag) +np.exp(b-c/Tau))
```

Here I use a variable `T` which is a combination of two independent variables `Tag` and `Tau`. The output that I wish to fit is `concentration`.

```
T=[(7.9481e-04,5.9061e-04), (7.64438e-04,6.1231e-04), (7.64438e-04,6.04905e-04), (7.85453e-04,6.01268e-04) ]
experimental_concentration = [0.5428,0.798,0.75,0.70]
```

My code says,

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

.

Comment: It looks like "(Tag,Tau)=T" should be "Tag, Tau = np.transpose(T)" to re-arrange the data into two individual arrays. Try that.

Comment: Please also show how you call `curve_fit`.